# Infinality problem with fonts in firefox

Tags: fonts

Just installed infinality in 13.10 from ppa:no1wantdthisname/ppa. And  got problem with fonts in Firefox. So when choose page source option in Firefox there is no any text inside window. Also on some sites whole areas of text dissapear.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Problem was with some ttf fonts, installed manually. So just removed it and reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer.